# return async function undefined in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, try-catch

Here, `plcs` variable within `try catch` function need to be used outside. I am trying calling `async` function directly and storing in `sync` function, both doesn't work, first method shows undefined and next one returns null promise

```
const fetch = () =>{
    const result=async()=>{
        try {
            const dbResult = await ftchplc();
            plcs= dbResult.rows._array;
            return plcs
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
    return result()
}    
const sample = fetch()
console.log(sample)


const result=async()=>{
    try {
        const dbResult = await ftchplc();
        plcs= dbResult.rows._array;
        return plcs
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
result()
const sample = result()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve here. But given that `ftchplc` is asynchronous and returns a promise, getting the `plcs` is always an asynchronous action and you will need to make your `console.log` wait for the result no matter what. Unnecessarily nesting the `result` function in a `fetch` function doesn't help anything.

Comment: ALL `async` functions return a promise.  So you will have to use `await` or `.then()` when you call an `async` function in order to get the resolved value.  `async` functions are useful INSIDE the function so you can use `await` internal to the function, but to the outside caller, it's still just a promise being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALL `async` functions return a promise. So you will have to use `await` or `.then()` when you call an `async` function in order to get the resolved value.

`async` functions are useful INSIDE the function so you can use `await` internal to the function, but to the outside caller, it's still just a promise being returned.  `async` functions to not turn an asynchronous result into a synchronous result. The caller of an `async` function still has to deal with an asynchronous response (in a promise).

For example:

```
async function fn() {
    const dbResult = await ftchplc();
    return dbResult.rows._array;
 };

fn().then(sample => {
    console.log(sample);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This assumes that `ftchplc()` returns a promise that resolves to your expected `dbResult`.